# Trying to find out the font style

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I’d like you to tell me the font the the person who wrote what’s in the picture
, is using:

[image]

Comment: It's (La)TeX's standard font, Computer Modern, or it's newer version, Latin Modern (which looks identical).

Comment: As Oleinik said, that is [the Computer Modern font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern), designed by Knuth. However, you may need to provide the source of the book you took the image on.

Comment: It is a thesis. It is in the public domain

Comment: @Delan Okay it may be available for public, but could I know who is the author? The license of the book has little chance of being WTFPL, so you need to (at least) provide sufficient information about the book.

Comment: @JouleV It is not a BOOK! It is an undergrad thesis / final project. I have no idea who the author is.

Comment: Are you a moderator or something like that? It would be awesome if you could (at least) provide some credentials.

Comment: @Delan No, I am not a moderator, but I am a person who wants to see legal contents.